# AWS RDS Database from Rails app - Error when switching from root to IAM user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-iam

I am accessing an `RDS PostgreSQL` database on `AWS` from a `rails` app I'm developing. Currently, I am accessing the database with my `AWS` root credentials.

In my `database.yml`:

```
pg_development:
  <<: *pg_default
  adapter: postgresql
  database: myDatabase
  username: myRootUsername
  password: myRootPassword
  host: myDatabase.1234.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
```

In production, they are stored in `Heroku` config vars.

This worked perfectly with my root credentials. I then set up an IAM user and group for more security. I have granted every policy that I could think of. I followed http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAM.html to the best of my ability...

In my dev environment I am seeing a rails error `PG::ConnectionBad FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "myIAMuser"`

In my `Heroku` logs it says `Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 59ms (ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)` and the same FATAL error I see in dev.

I have never used `IAM` before and I am hoping that I am just making a simple mistake and the method of passing credentials is different with `IAM`.

I have tried restarting servers, switching back to root to make sure I didn't mess anything else up to cause the error, `rake db:migrate`, couldn't think of anything else that would cause this.

Comment: Most likely it's a problem with your policies or IAM settings. It's by far not the most intuitive thing in the world, and there are a lot of places mistakes can be easily made. I would suggest to re-do all the steps and record them, and if it still doesn't work, post the steps here for others to take a look.

Comment: Thanks. So you are confirming that I should be able to use the password (that is use to sign into the AWS platform) is all I should need to use as my authentication password in my app? The same as I would for the root user.

Comment: Not at all. Ideally you should set up an IAM user to access the DB.

Comment: Right. What I'm saying is that I create an IAM user, that IAM user would have a password and I'd use the password for the IAM user as authentication to access the database. Just trying to make sure that I don't have to use anything other than the password for authentication if I'm not using the root user.

Comment: Postgres is not aware of IAM users at all. An IAM user can only be used to call AWS API methods, it cannot be used to login to an RDS database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing IAM users with database users...

The IAM user, is a user within AWS (one that may be able to log into the management console for example, or use an SDK functionality to launch ec2 instaces, created RDS databases, write data to S3 and so on).

When you launch a RDS instance, you must specify an admin/root username and password. My guess is that this is the username and password that works (note that this username and password does not identify an IAM user).

If you want to narrow down the database access of you application, you need to create a new database user inside the RDS PostgreSQL itself (using a Postgre GUI of some sort, or by connecting the Postgre database and issuing CREATE USER).

Comment: That was my issue. Thanks for saving me a lot of time.